# Detecting trends in local business web services

Tags: google-maps, business

Do you know any research paper about spatial data mining algorithms to retrieve trends about local business services (such as google places.. etc)

let's say most rated restaurants this week.. etc ?

I need scientific material about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be worth looking into hyperlocal journalism. [Everyblock](http://www.everyblock.com/) is a good example of that.

Comment: Very cool indeed, thanks... so basically.. there is not a web service displaying all events on the map ?

Comment: FYI, everyblock has ["closed it's doors"](http://blog.everyblock.com/2013/feb/07/goodbye/).

Comment: @Fezter hmm ... there goes the neighborhood.

Answer (score -1):

I have a link somewhere. Can't find it right now but Bing is doing some of this with geo blog, geotweet, and geotag photos. There was not any scientific info in the link but very interesting concepts.

Sounds much like Kirk's hyperlocal journalism.